# Realm crash realm::util::terminate(char const*, char const*, long, std::initializer_list<realm::util::Printable>&&)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, rx-swift

I am using Realm in my project.
so far it was working correctly but now we are getting crash. & strange thing is its not reproducible by debugging.

> realm::util::terminate(char const*, char const*, long,
> std::initializer_listrealm::util::Printable&&)

I have checked from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift i am using latest version of Realm libraries & Xcode 12.3.

I am here attaching screensot of Firebase which helps you better understand.
On firebase event it shows that it crashes on some devices with app launch on second time.

[image]

Comment: A Firebase crash log showing a Realm crash does't really help us unless we know in what context the app is crashing. The question is also unclear. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please update and clarify the question and we'll take a look. Also, please do some troubleshooting - without seeing whatever code is crashing, we would purely be guessing at a solution